# How to underline groups of letters in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a text "RESET" and i need to underline it like this: RE must be underlined, S must have dashed underline, and ET must be underlined; The problem is  that letter "S" must have 2 dashes.

And the second thing, what property should I apply on active text, that make it less bold than actual?

I tried to do something but I can't figure it out...here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="section8">
            <p><span style="color:#fdd400; font-size:30px">Partners</span></p>
            <div class="content8">
                <ul id="nav8">
                    <li><a href="#">RESET</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><u>R</u><u>E</u><span style="border-bottom-style: dotted">S</span><u>ET</u></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RESET</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RESET</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RESET</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.section8
{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.content8
{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#nav8 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    font-size:25px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:14.5%;
    margin-top:-17px;
    color:#6e6e6e;
    letter-spacing: 4px;

}
#nav8 li 
{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    color: red;
}

#nav8 a 
{
    color: #7b7979;
    text-decoration:overline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `text-decoration: underline` on 2 letters and `border-bottom` on one letter which doesn't align the lines horizontally, you can wrap `RE`and `ET` inside `<span class="underlined">` and `S` inside `<span class="underlined">` and then style them using `border-bottom`. Here's a demo:

```css
.section8 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content8 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#nav8 {
  list-style: none outside none;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 14.5%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
#nav8 li {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
#nav8 a {
  color: #7b7979;
  text-decoration: overline;
}
span.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
span.singleunderline {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="section8">
  <p><span style="color:#fdd400; font-size:30px">Partners</span>
  </p>
  <div class="content8">
    <ul id="nav8">
      <li><a href="#">RESET</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">RESET</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">RESET</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">RESET</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution but if you change the font size you end up with one or multiple dashed lines instead of two.

Comment: @Moogs The two-dashes stay there till 34px and I believe OP already has the styles of his navigation menu applied sorted out since there's a `font-size` of `25px` applied to `#nav8`.

Comment: That's right, I have fixed text dimension of 25px :)

Answer (score 0):

For the bottom border you can use the border bottom width property

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><u>R</u><u>E</u><span style="border-bottom-style:  dotted ; border-bottom-width:5px">S</span><u>ET</u></a></li>
```

And for the font use  `font-weight: normal;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to always get two dashes under the letter s:

```css
.reset {
 display: inline;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 65px;
}
.reset:active {
 font-weight: 100;
}
.re {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.s {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 border-right: 2px solid #fff;
 border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
.s:before {
 content:"";
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 width: 45%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
.s:after {
 content:"";
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 width: 45%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
.et {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="reset">
  <span class="re">RE</span><span class="s">S</span><span class="et">ET</span>
</div>
```